# Inject rows from table using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, optimization, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem, which is connected to Selenium webdriver usage.
Imagine that I have an HTML-table, which has a `<head>` and `<body>` and table body consists of 200 rows.

What I need to do is to map each `<th>` in `<head>` with list of cells (`tbody//tr//th`) that corresponds to this `<th>`.

For example, if we have table:

```
<table>
    <head>
        <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
        </tr>
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>...199 more such rows...</tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

What I want to receive as a result is a `HashMap<WebElement, List<WebElement>>` where key is a column title and value is list of cells (`body//tr//td`) which corresponds to column index.

I have already implemented this, but I faced problem with time overhead when there are a lot of rows in table.

Here is how I have done this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//table)
WebElement table;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//table//head")
WebElement tableHeader;

Map<WebElement, List<WebElement>> columnCells = new HashMap<>();
List<WebElement> tableTitles = tableHeader.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/*"));

for (int i = 0; i < tableTitles.size(); i++) {
    WebElement columnTitle = tableTitles.get(i);
    List<WebElement> correspondingCells = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement tableRow : tableRows) {
        List<WebElement> cells = tableRow.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
        correspondingCells.add(cells.get(i));
    }
    columnCells.put(columnTitle, chosenCells);
}
```

As I mentioned, this initialization takes about 15 seconds if table consists of ~200 rows. The problem is in the second `for` loop, because accessing WebDriver once costs about 6-8 milliseconds. 
Could someone help me to optimize this table initialization? Maybe there is a way not to involve WebDriver at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in an easier way by xpath using index.

Assuming you got `N columns` in the table and `200 plus rows`.

1. Get all the  **elements** and setup the for loop exactly what you have done.
2. Use an xpath with an **index from for loop (say i)** to get all the td -- `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[i+1]"));` Returns a list of elements which you can put in your collection.

Make sure you do the plus 1 logic before querying as xpath index starts at 1.

Comment: Thank you!
I also came to this solution :)

Comment: Anyway, this approach took about 10 seconds with 200 rows column. Don't you know a way how to avoid webdriver usage?

Comment: You can try connecting to the webpage directly through Java using connect method of URL class and parsing the html content. Or have a look at jsoup - https://jsoup.org/. I never used it but it has got methods for finding html easily. Guess jsoup is a wrapper around java api.

Comment: What happens on subsequent run of the webdriver code? Does the time taken decrease?

Comment: Yes, it decreases for about 5 seconds, which is good.
But still not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Even without caring much about how exactly it works, it's nearly sure that the time-consuming part is the line

```
List<WebElement> cells = tableRow.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
```

wher you get all cells in a row and throw all but one away. Switching the loops will surely be much faster. You can use all the cells and distribute them into an appropriate list.

---

Consider replacing `Map<WebElement, List<WebElement>> columnCells` by a [ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) from Guava. This alone won't help the speed, but it makes the code simpler.

---

The Multimap makes the optimized loop shorter than the original:

```
for (WebElement tableRow : tableRows) {
    List<WebElement> cells = tableRow.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
    for (int i = 0; i < tableTitles.size(); i++) {
        columnCells.put(tableTitles.get(i), cells.get(i)); // using Multimap
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advises!